# Why would gcc movl to the same register?

Tags: assembly

For this piece of C code:

```
uint64_t roundUp(uint64_t value, uint32_t blockSize) 
{
    return (value + blockSize - 1) & ~(blockSize - 1);
}
```

gcc 4.6 -O3 generated the following assembly:

```
roundUp(unsigned long, unsigned int):
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    %esi, %edx
    movl    %esi, %esi
    leaq    -1(%rdi,%rsi), %rax
    negl    %edx
    andl    %edx, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Could anyone tell me why would it want to do this?

```
movl    %esi, %esi
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That clears the upper 32 bits. When you write to a 32 bit register in x86-64, the upper 32 bits are cleared automatically. Since `esi` contains a 32 bit parameter, the upper 32 bits could contain any value, so they need to be cleared before `rsi` can be used.

Comment: but the instruction immediately above writes to esi

Comment: @wowest No, this is not intel syntax. The destination operand is the second one.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw thats enlightening, thanks. Would you also care to explain how (blockSize - 1) ends up in %edx? I can see how blockSize ends up there, but blockSize - 1?

Comment: @Inso That's what the `negl` instruction does. It is a 2's complement negation, which complements each bit and adds one, so negating blockSize is the same as `~(blockSize - 1)`.

Comment: But then it proceeds to use %rsi in such a way that the upper bits are irrelevant anyway, so why are they cleared at all?

Comment: harold, Second argument is 32bits wide so the upper 64bit of the first argument are irrelevant for andl

Comment: @InsoReiges right, so why are they cleared then? Might as well leave garbage in there - the AND will remove it.